# A line of code is showing as well as the webpage

Tags: php

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once "incfiles/connectdb.php";
include_once "incfiles/func.php";
$page="gamepoints.php";
logincheck();
$username=$_SESSION['username'];
$fetch=mysql_fetch_object(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE username='$username'"));

if ($_GET['item']){

$item=strip_tags($_GET['item']); 

if ($item == "LHP"){ $cost="50"; $amount="10000"; }
elseif ($item == "FMJ"){ $cost="70"; $amount="15000"; }
elseif ($item == "rankpoints"){ $cost="150"; $amount="10000"; }
elseif ($item == "awp"){ $cost="300"; $amount="1"; }
elseif ($item == "credits"){ $cost="50"; $amount="10"; }
elseif ($item == "money"){ $cost="300"; $amount="5000000"; }
```

From if if ($item == "LHP") to the end is what shows up on my webpage along with the page and I can't seem to figure out why

Comment: is this really a copy/paste of your code?

Comment: are you sure it's just that code? Did you do a 'view source' to see if the rest of the php does? Remember that `<?` will be interpreted as an invalid HTML tag by the browser if the php code does leak through to the client.

Comment: @SakhalTurkaystan if document is just PHP-code it is not recommended to use `?>`. It can cause many problems.

Comment: That's half of it but okay I will consider what you few have said thanks and will post back with results! http://i.gyazo.com/60ddf73872dc75d4a2ee21a2b076bf2e.png This is the webpage

Comment: Thanks for all your help it has been fixed!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is all of your code - if it is, looks like you might be missing the last `}`.

```
<?php
    session_start();
    include_once "incfiles/connectdb.php";
    include_once "incfiles/func.php";

    $page="gamepoints.php";

    logincheck();

    $username=$_SESSION['username'];
    $fetch=mysql_fetch_object(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE username='$username'"));

    if ($_GET['item']){
        $item=strip_tags($_GET['item']); 

        if ($item == "LHP"){ $cost="50"; $amount="10000"; }
        elseif ($item == "FMJ"){ $cost="70"; $amount="15000"; }
        elseif ($item == "rankpoints"){ $cost="150"; $amount="10000"; }
        elseif ($item == "awp"){ $cost="300"; $amount="1"; }
        elseif ($item == "credits"){ $cost="50"; $amount="10"; }
        elseif ($item == "money"){ $cost="300"; $amount="5000000"; }
    }
```